# How to check if a pair exists using HQL in query?

Tags: java, hql

I have a list of different ids and their names. For every `id[0]` we have `name[0]` that needs to be matched.

- list of ids, `l{1,2,3,4};`
- list of names, `n{a,b,c,d};`

Now suppose if I want to get an exact match for both above combination, is there any way in HQL to get the result?

I am looking to find a replacement for a query like:

```sql
select any_column 
from table_name 
where (id[0]=1 and name[0]=a) or (id[1]=2 and name[1]=b and so on...);
```

The HQL query should be something like below:

```sql
select any_column 
from table_name 
where (id,name) IN {(id[0],name[0]), (id[1], name[1]),...};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not hql/sql guy, however one way I can think of is, in your hql, you concatenate the id and name with a space (or other special char) then with `in` sub-clause. something like:

```
select * from table where concat(id, ' ', name) in (:pairList)
```

The `pairList` parameter is a java collection, you should prepare before the hql query call, which has element `id[x] + " " + name[x]`.

I think this should work.

If you are using hibernate, another possible solution is, make use of the hibernate's `@Formular` annotation on your `table` entity, to create a calculated column, such as:

```
@Formula(value = " concat(id, ' ', name) ")
private String idNamePair;
```

Then you can in hql use it as a normal field. like `... from table where idNamePair in (:paramList)`